ASPX life cycle prevents ScriptManager to be run
in my ASp.NET Form, This is the part of my code
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "ActionField", "ActionField();", true);
 UpdatePanel1.Update();
 .......
 Page.Response.Redirect(@"~/DownloadFile.ashx", false);

So becuase of the Page.Response.Redirect , the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript never run, becuase of the life cycle of the page, how can I force ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript run the javasacript on the Frontend page and after that the response.redirect executed?

Hi, i don't exaclty understand what you are doing... you have and updatepanel and you want to raise the actionfield after the page is loaded by Page.Response.Redirect?

You cannot run the script because the page is never shown in the browser. If you want to execute a script then don't download with a postback with response.redirect in it.

@VDWWD: I am on the page AA.aspx, when I click a button , in the method some fields on frontend would be reset by ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript and also A file would be downloaded by Page.Response.Redirect(@"~/DownloadFile.ashx", false);  but the browser still shows the AA.aspx

@nnmmss don't download file by Response.Redirect, instead use js script to download the file e.g. after the ActionField() method executed, write js to download the file window.open('/Download.ashx')

The simple matter is with a response.redirect, then the current page is NEVER sent to the client side. The "false" parameter of the response.redirect allows the code behind to continue to run (and does not terminate), but that still means the page is not rendered and sent to the client side with your response.redirect. So the "false" means the code on the page does continue to run, but you still never see that page rendered, do you? (and hence thus any changes to controls (or the DOM), updates etc. or script injection simply never is seen nor run.

if i understand well you call the page with Page.Redirect.
When page is loaded you would to use ActionField method..
With jquery..
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    ActionField();
});
</script>

The actionfield will called after page is completely loaded..

OP redirects to other url before even the aspx is loaded in browser so it wont emit any HTML, so it will never reach document ready
